# How to jump a commit in the same branch at git

Tags: git

Suppose I'm in the branch `develop`.

I'm in commit `(A)` and I do some bad things and make another commit `(B)`.

Supposing that undoing the bad things I did is a very painful job, how can I manage to put another commit ahead of `(B)` in the same branch `develop`?

```
CURRENT STATE:
 _______________________________________
|develop|   (A) ----> (B)
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾

WHAT I IMAGINE:
 _______________________________________
|develop|   (A) ----> (B)       (D)
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
             |                   | 
 _______________________________|______
|bugfix |   (C) -----------------'
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

I have no intention of merging, since I don't want to utilize `(B)`. I also cannot erase `(B)`, so doing  force push isn't an option.

What should I do in this situation?

If there is a way to put a new commit (ahead of `(B)`) whose state is equal to `(A)`, this would be also an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can '[revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)' B.  This effectively creates a new commit which 'undoes' the changes made by B.  This works with one bad commit or a whole series of bad commits.